# How to provide the reset password feature outside Azure context?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My scenario is a public website, with authenticated access that is managed by AzureAdB2C, and the authentication is not embedded but on a subdomain style. In the authentication form I see that there's the option for password reset (for someone who forgets it) but my question is when the user is already authenticated and so outside Azure context, how can he ask for a password change?

Is there any endpoint or so (that would receive the email linked to the account)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not clear because you mention "fire the change/reset password flow?". Which is it or is it both?

If reset, you can use a [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). Just put the link to the policy on your page.

There are a number of password reset [flows](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples) that may be of interest.

For change password, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). Again, just put the policy link on the page.

Unsure if you would have to login again.

Comment: Thank you. When I said "change/reset" i meant "change", as in, the user knows his password but he wants to change it.  And my doubt (and since i'm new to AzureAD) was if it was possible to have a link somewhere in my CMS pages to that feature (change password). From your response (and the above @rickvdbosch) I'm thinking that it is. We'll have to setup a custom policy and then (somewhere) there'll be a link to take the user to change his password. Does this sound about right?

Answer (score 1):

You can [Configure password change using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

> In Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C), you can enable users who are signed in with a local account to change their password without having to prove their identity through email verification. The password change flow involves following steps:
>
> 1. The user signs in to their local account. If the session is still active, Azure AD B2C authorizes the user and skips to the next step.
> 2. The user verifies the **Old password**, and then creates and confirms the **New password**.

If the question is to reset the password because the user forgot it but is still logged in, I can imagine logging out the user and redirecting them to the login page where they can choose the reset password option.

**EDIT:**

The Azure AD B2C article [Set up self-service password reset for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-self-service-password-reset) states that

> This article applies to self-service password reset used in the context of the standard **Sign in** user flow, which uses **Local Account SignIn** as the identity provider. If you need fully customizable password reset user flows invoked from your app, see [**this article**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview).

Somehow resetting your password with a password reset flow / custom policy while you're logged in and don't 'need' your current password feels weird.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The question is how to make available a link for password reset, while the user is authenticated on my site, without forcing him to logout and login. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I think I did a poor job explaining myself.. I do expect the user to see a form that requires the old password.. the thing is that I'm new to AzureAD, and in my head the flow is something like: 1) access to my website 2) click login 3) navigates to azuread context to authenticate 4) gets a JWT and moves on to the CMS that suports the website. Now, when inside the website how to fire the change/reset password flow? In what I'd call "usual" way, I'd have an API for password changes, but with AzureAD is different. Sorry for the mess, and really thank you for your time.